# indoor atlas: using the API offline?

Tags: android, xamarin

I am using the indoor atlas API. I am wondering if there is a way to work with the API affline and have a valid magnetic map offline, so my application wont be dependant on the state of the cloud servor?

Comment: You can use [Tile Overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/tileoverlay) with [MapBox](https://www.mapbox.com/) to make offline maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no offline solution today. Newest SDK can handle the situations when the network breaks for a while, but the accuracy decreases the longer you stay offline.